# Google Apps Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to develop a form. I have created it and am getting responses in a worksheet. However, after amendment I am getting blank columns where changes were made. 
I tried deleting the Response sheet but it appears not to make a difference.

Secondly is there a way of running a script when the Form Submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

Reconnect the form to the response sheet or create a new response sheet.
You are not supposed to mess with the response sheet data or format.

## 2:

see trigger onFormSubmit